# mssql one month beetwen dates

Tags: sql-server, date

I have table where there are two columns, date_from and date_to. And there are few rows, for example

```
1   2016-08-01   2016-12-31
2   2017-01-01   2017-08-01
3   2017-08-02   2017-12-31
```

I need put the row inside between 2'nd and 3'nd row. with date range like one previous month, so result should be like for november:

```
1   2016-08-01   2016-12-31
2   2017-01-01   2017-08-01
3   2017-08-02   2017-09-30
4   2017-10-01   2017-10-31
5   2017-11-01   2017-12-31
```

What are the best and simple solution for task like above ?

thanks for feedback
reagrds
malin

Comment: Can you explain why the only the range in the third row is getting expanded, while the first two rows are not?

Comment: Because the previous month are October and I need put row with October period chronologically, so I need to end the 3rd row with last day of September then put the row with October in 4th row and then open 5th row with first day of November and rest date form first table

Comment: no body can't give me some feedback ?